# How do I use rails 2.3.8 with declarative authorization on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, declarative-authorization

help rails 3 came out yesterday, 
we have a fully functional rails 2.3.8 app, but our deployment on heroku doesn't work because declarative_authorization demands rails 2.1 or **higher**

That is a very big problem, how can I solve it, any quick hacks, workarounds?

Comment: if the dependency is 2.1 or higher and you are running 2.3.8, then whats the issue?

Comment: the problem is, that declarative authorization will install rails 3 because it demands rails 2.1 or higher.
It will always go for the higher option

Comment: Post your .gems file; your problem is in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `.gems` file starts with:

```
rails --version=2.3.8
```

But as you've stated, declarative_authorization will then go an install the Rails 3.0.0 gems over the top of your rails install, breaking the lot. You can get around this in your gems manifest, by using:

```
declarative_authorization --ignore-dependencies
```

Of course, you'll also need to separately include each dependency for declarative_authorization in your gems manifest.

Comment: thanks, but this does not work. We have specified rails --version=2.3.8 in .gems (and it gets loaded) the problem is, that declarative_authorization has this line

  s.add_dependency('rails', '>= 2.1.0')

you can see it here

http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization/blob/master/declarative_authorization.gemspec

what can we do? :(

Comment: I ran a quick test app and had the same problem - but i've updated my answer above with a solution.